# "manufacturing sector" vs. "manufacturing industries"

Tags: economic-terms

[From a tutorial](https://www.economicshelp.org/blog/12436/concepts/sectors-economy/)

> The main sectors of the economy are: Primary **sector**, Secondary / manufacturing **sector**, Service / ‘tertiary’ sector, Quaternary sector

which uses the word "sector", [so does Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manufacturing).

While some other posts, e.g. the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/manufacturing-industry), and [hq.nasa](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/iwgsdi/Manufacturing.html) use another word "industry". Which one is the professional term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how industry and sectors are defined.  In a few settings they could be used to mean the same thing.

However, **usually**, the term industry refers to a much more specific group of companies or businesses, while the term sector describes a large segment of the economy.

Industry can be used to define the group of organizations or firms that are engaged in the production of related goods or services.  The industry name will depend on the type of service or product made.     Sectors describes the division of the whole economy, which can consist of business groups(multiple industries) which are engaged in related or similar services or products.

Industry are a cluster of different firms while a sector are a group of different related industries.

Since an industry involves a particular process the scope it is more narrow while for a sector it relates to business activities which makes its scope wider.

https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/industry-vs-sector/